# Using tqdm to track progress in slow REST-requests: progress for filling lists

Tags: python, list, rest, progress, tqdm

I have a function where I use REST-requests. The function requests data from a remote Confluence server in chunks. Each chunk requests 25 results from a REST API.

```py
 for result in response.json()['results']:
            user = dict()
            user['group'] = result['name']
            groups.append(user)
        size = response.json()['size']
        start += chunk
    return groups
```

The `result` variable contains these requested 25 results from a REST-request. Results are returned in a dictionary. So I get values from the returned dictionary and then store them in a new dictionary.

Then I make the next query and get following 25 results as a new `user` dictionary.

Finally, I add all dictionaries to the `groups` list. As a result, the function returns a list consiting of multiple dictionaries.

More on this:

I use this function to collect data in a dataframe and output to a file. Because my function retrives a list of dictionaries, I expand the result to a single list as follows.

```py
groups = list()

print('Retrieving groups:')
groups.extend(get_groups())
df = pd.DataFrame(
     groups, 
     columns = ['group']
    )
```

**The question is: how do I track the progress of how the `group` list gets filled with dictionaries?** Currently this `print('Retrieving groups:')` steps takes a lot of time, and I want some progress bar to track the go.

I thought of

```py
tqdm.pandas(desc="desc")
for user in tqdm(groups):
    pass
```

Within the `get_groups()` function, but this doesn't seem the right way to do so. I'd apreciate your help. TIA.